# Padding Function (Python) string.zfill

Tags: python, pandas, etl

I would like to change the below Python function to cover all situations in which my business_code will need padding.  The `string.zfill` Python function handles this exception, padding to the left until a given width is reached but I have never used it before.

```
 #function for formating business codes
def formatBusinessCodes(code):
    """ Function that formats business codes.  Pass in a business code which will convert to a string with 6 digits """
    busCode=str(code)
    if len(busCode)==1:
        busCode='00000'+busCode
    elif len(busCode)==2:
        busCode='0000'+busCode
    else:
        if len(busCode)==3:
            busCode='000'+busCode
    return busCode

#pad extra zeros 
df2['business_code']=df2['business_code'].apply(lambda x: formatBusinessCodes(x))
businessframe['business_code']=businessframe['business_code'].apply(lambda x: formatBusinessCodes(x))
financialframe['business_code']=financialframe['business_code'].apply(lambda x: formatBusinessCodes(x))
```

The code above handles a business_code of length 6 but I'm finding that the business_codes vary in length < and > 6.  I'm validating data state by state.  Each state varies in their business_code lengths (IL - 6 len, OH - 8 len).  All codes must be padded evenly. So a code for IL that is 10 should produce 000010, etc.  I need to handle all exceptions.  Using a command line parsing parameter (argparse), and string.zfill.

Comment: What's your problem with `string.zfill` exactly?

Comment: My problem is I'm getting a TypeError: zfill() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given).  Im passing in a parsing paramter, asking the user the length of the business code (parser.add_argument('-b',help='Specify length of the business code', businessformat=args.d).  I'm unsure how to bring in the argument using string.zfill (def formatBusinessCodes(code):, str.zfill(code))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [str.format](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
def formatBusinessCodes(code):
    """ Function that formats business codes.  Pass in a business code which will convert to a string with 6 digits """
    return '{:06d}'.format(code)
```

---

```
In [23]: formatBusinessCodes(1)
Out[25]: '000001'

In [26]: formatBusinessCodes(10)
Out[26]: '000010'

In [27]: formatBusinessCodes(123)
Out[27]: '000123'
```

---

The format `{:06d}` can be understood as follows:

- `{...}` means replace the following with an argument from `format`,
  (e.g. `code`).
- `:` begins the format specification
- `0` enables zero-padding
- `6` is the width of the string. Note that numbers larger than 6
  digits will NOT be truncated, however.
- `d` means the argument (e.g. `code`) should be of integer type.

---

Note in Python2.6 the format string needs an extra 0:

```
def formatBusinessCodes(code):
    """ Function that formats business codes.  Pass in a business code which will convert to a string with 6 digits """
    return '{0:06d}'.format(code)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parser.add_argument('-b',help='Specify length of the district code')   
businessformat=args.d 
businessformat=businessformat.strip() 

df2['business_code']=df2['business_code'].apply(lambda x: str(x)) 

def formatBusinessCodes(code): 
bus=code bus.zfill(4) 
return bus 

formatBusinessCodes(businessformat)
```